UA client open62541 can't connect server in docker
I have trouble with connect client to server by username and password in docker container.
It returns:
Rejecting UserTokenPolicy 0 (username) in endpoint 0: configuration doesn't match
Rejecting UserTokenPolicy 1 (username) in endpoint 0: configuration doesn't match
Rejecting UserTokenPolicy 2 (certificate) in endpoint 0: configuration doesn't match
Rejecting UserTokenPolicy 3 (certificate) in endpoint 0: configuration doesn't match
Rejecting UserTokenPolicy 4 (anonymous) in endpoint 0: configuration doesn't match

error/client       No suitable UserTokenPolicy found for the possible endpoints

it is interesting that in local ubuntu runs without mistake and connection is established successfully. I'm not skilled with docker, but seems that something is missing...
Can someone help me, please?
dockerfile below
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential git gcc g++ gdb make wget cmake iputils-ping ca-certificates pkg-config libmbedtls-dev libtinyxml-dev rapidjson-dev libsoup2.4-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/libs/open62541-master
RUN mkdir -p build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/libs/open62541-master/build

RUN cmake .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DUA_ENABLE_ENCRYPTION=MBEDTLS
RUN make

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/libs/open62541-master/build/bin

RUN cp /usr/src/app/libs/open62541-master/build/bin/libopen62541.a /usr/src/app

ENV LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/app/libs/open62541-master/build/bin
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN ./build.sh

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/src/app/libs/open62541-master/build/bin
ENV DISPLAY=:0

CMD ["./adapter_OPCUA"]


What are you trying to connect to?  What code makes that connection?  How do you provide the credentials to the application?  The build information in the Dockerfile is interesting, but it would help if you could [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

@DavidMaze is asking some very important questions here! Also the way how you start the docker container would be interesting.
Since you mentioned open62541: did you try the example client? Does it work local and in docker? Did you take care of the ports in your docker container (for OPC-UA usually 4840 and 4843)?
